# I would like to set my variables at the top of my class instead of in the method

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to tackle this confusing problem, I have lots and lots of things that I would like to add at the top of my class to help cut down on clutter.

Since multiple methods use these checkbox variables.

I would like to have everything at the top directly under the opening bracket.

Here's what works, but *not* what I want.:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //leaving out most code like onCreate. Just pretend it's there.

    public void checkboth(View view) {

        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);

            cb1.setchecked(true);
            cb2.setchecked(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out why I can't do this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);

    //leaving out most code like onCreate. Just pretend it's there.

    public void checkboth(View view) {            

        cb1.setchecked(true);
        cb2.setchecked(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't initialize `View`s outside of a method like this

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
```

because that would mean that these lines run before `onCreate()` which results in these variables being `null` and throw a `NPE` when you try to call methods on these variables. This is because you call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` inside of `onCreate()` and your `Views` "live" inside of that `layout`. This means that they can't be initialized until your `layout` has been `inflated` by calling `setContentView()`. You **must call `setContentView()` before trying to initialize your `Views`**. There is no way around that part.

What some people do that might help is to create a separate function that initializes these variables just after `setContentView()` is called. Something like this

```
public class MyActivity
    // declare your Views so they are global to the class
    TextView tv;
   // more views
    @Override
    public void onCreat(stuff)
    {
       // super call
       setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
       init();
```

then in your `init()` function initialize all of the `Views` you have declared

```
private void init()
{
     tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
     // more initializations
}
```

but you can just initialize them in `onCreate()`, `onResume()` or wherever as long as it's **after** `setContentView()`
Declaring and initializing them in this way will make sure they are all available to other functions, listeners, inner classes, etc... of the `Activity`. And if you have a lot of `Views` it may lessen the "clutter" a bit.

Comment: Thanks, this will do nicely.

Answer (score 2):

findViewById is a method that can be run from the activity (or any view group) after the view has been inflated. To inflate a view a the activity level, you usually call setContentView.

Since setContentView has not been called yet, no views are attached to the activity.

Here is how to do it

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


        CheckBox cb1;
        CheckBox cb2;

        public void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
            super.onCreate(sis);
            setContentView(R.layout.whatever);

            cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
            cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        }

        public void checkboth(View view) {

            cb1.setchecked(true);   
            cb2.setchecked(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would use this if I didn't have so much in my onCreate already, but thanks. You re-enforced everyone else's answer.

Comment: This is why it is recommended to make the move to using Fragments to organize your UI. My activities usually only attach the fragment/forward lifecycle events to a fragment, so that view code can be incapsulated with the UI rather than with the activity. Something to look into if you are interested in keeping your code clean

Answer (score 1):

You can't call method (findViewById) from here and expect a non null value.  The views are only created in android after you call setContentView(R.layout.my_layout).  What you have to do is something like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

CheckBox cb1 = null;
CheckBox cb2 = null;

//leaving out most code like onCreate. Just pretend it's there.
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);   
}

public void checkboth(View view) {            

    cb1.setchecked(true);
    cb2.setchecked(true);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move the declarations to the top of the class, you change local variables to fields. These fields are initialized when an instance is created - which means they are initialized "right before" the constructor executes.

Now, you can not call instance methods (like `findViewById`) before the implicit call to `super()` finishes.

Move them to the constructor, and things should work out.